# Building a Trending query

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to build a query that returns a record set consisting of a date and the number of records == that date? For example, I have a DB that is tracking inspections that take place on every day. I want to build a data set to be used for a trending graph to see how many inspections took place on each day streching back 365 days.

Record set desired would look like this:

```
date | InspectionCount
2013-12-30  265
2013-12-29  123
2013-12-28  425
.
.
.
2013-01-01  15
```

Is there a way to do that without write code that will simple loop through 365 times and sort of manually generate daily counts like this:

```
select count(reporting_id) as InspectionCount
from inspection
where close_conf_date >= '2013-12-30'
and close_conf_date < '2013-12-31'
```

while gradually winding the clock back 365 days? Please let me know if you need more info.

**Update**

I have just tried this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
VALUES (cast('2013-12-30' as timestamp))
UNION ALL
SELECT n-interval '1 day' FROM t WHERE n >=('2013-12-30'-interval '365 day')
)
SELECT  cast(t.n as date) as date_column, count(reporting_id) 
FROM t
INNER JOIN inspection i ON (cast(t.n as date) = cast(i.close_conf_date as date))
GROUP BY cast(t.n as date)
```

and I am getting this error i do not really understand:
*interval field value out of range: "2013-12-30"*

Comment: If you don't care about days with 0 inspections, just use a regular sum/group by query. Otherwise you'll need interval and windowed functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the recursive CTE, just use `generate_series()`:

You also need to use an outer join in order for the days without inspection to show up as zero:

```
with days as (
  select day::date
  from generate_series(date '2013-12-30', date '2013-12-30' + 365, interval '1' day) day
) 
select d.day as date_column, 
       count(i.reporting_id) as cnt
from days d
  left join inspection i on i.date = d.day
group by d.day
```

`generate_series(date '2013-12-30', date '2013-12-30' + 365, interval '1' day)` generates one row for each date between '2013-12-30' and '2013-12-30' + 365. For details on `generate_series()` see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

The `::date` notation  is just a shorthand for `cast(.. as date)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive query to generate 365 rows and join your original query with it . For instance (recursive part) :

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (cast(current_date as timestamp))
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n-interval '1 day' FROM t WHERE n >=(current_date-interval '365 day')
)
SELECT  cast(n as date) as date_column FROM t;
```

All together (one year running total - from today minus 365 days till today)

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
        VALUES (cast(current_date as timestamp))
      UNION ALL
        SELECT n-interval '1 day' FROM t WHERE n >=(current_date-interval '365 day')
    )
    SELECT  cast(t.n as date) as date_column, count(reporting_id) 
    FROM t
    INNER JOIN inspection i ON (cast(t.n as date) = cast(i.close_conf_date as date))
    GROUP BY cast(t.n as date)
```

You may use " n > ..." instead of  ">= ..." if it returns more days then needed. Also, casting i.close_conf_date to date might be redundant

Comment: What does n stand for, 2013-12-31? How would directly translate my query above into what you have there? Thanks.

Comment: check updated version. In case I misunderstood the question (I thought you need a running total), just change `current_date` to whatever end date you want.

Comment: I have updated what i have tried so far in the main question, and the error that i get. Do i have the dates backwards?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato : do `date '2013-12-30' - interval ....`  : ` .... SELECT n-interval '1 day' FROM t WHERE n >=(date '2013-12-30'-interval '365 day') ....`